# VSCode warning every variable

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

My python code has yellow underlines under nearly everything
[It underlines print but when I run it still shows.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EynXU.png)

Any help would be appreciated!

I tried to change the python intepriter but that didnt work and i also reinstalled the python extention. I also reset VScode settings.json file.

It still did not fix.

Comment: Click the "PROBLEMS" tab at the bottom left and see what the error is

Comment: Or place the cursor over the `print` statement and see what the tooltip says...

Answer (score 1):

If you enable ***linting***, some warnings will be prompted but it will not affect the normal operation of the code. Those are just some things that are code normative.

Add the following setting in the *settings.json* to turn off linting:

```json
    "python.linting.enabled": false,
```

*If you have additional linter extensions installed, you will need to turn off the setting individually or disable that extension.*

[*More about linting in vscode*](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting).

Answer (score -1):

Yellow underline are warnings, your code will still works. If the yellow space at the bottom of the page with "3.10.10" is your pyhton version, it might be because it wants you to update your Python.

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work as the version it says I am on is 3.11.2. FYI: i have deleted all other versions.

Comment: Warnings shouldn't be ignored. They often hint at a larger problem.